# How to send request in raw format in Java with restassured

Tags: java, rest-assured

My client is asking me to perform test for api where the body of the request should one in raw instead of header or something else.

He showed me how to do it in postman, but samething I want to simulate through automation which is in Java and rest assured.

[image]

Then How to approach the same in java becasue I can do it through get or post in java and restassured but dont know how to do it with raw.

GET-

```
@Test
    public void mytest() {

        Map<String, String> paramSample = new HashMap<>();
        paramSample.put("v", "X.X");
        paramSample.put("headers", "X");
        paramSample.put("local", "X");
        paramSample.put("method", "xxxxx");
        paramSample.put("json", CreateJSON(ExecutionConfig.xxxx,0,0,ExecutionConfig.xxxxx,"Mex"));
        paramSample.put("sender", ExecutionConfig.xxxx);
        paramSample.put("api_key", ExecutionConfig.xxx);
        paramSample.put("format", "json");
        RequestSpecification request = given();
        Response responseSample = request.params(paramSample).get(ExecutionConfig.Mxxxxx).then().extract().response();
```

Comment: You can just set given().contentType("text/plain")

Comment: @Wilfred Clement I done that but where I need to pass the raw body content?

Comment: Can I ask why you're passing a body for a GET call ? There is no point in passing a body for a GET call

Comment: This is how I got it from client and also they said it will work with get & Post method.

Comment: A POST method will have a payload but a GET will never have one

Comment: okay, thanks for the information but now if I want to do it with post here with this raw format, how to do it with restassured ?

Comment: @SobhitSharma, Did you try Response responseSample = request.contentType("text/plain").params(paramSample).get(ExecutionConfig.Mxxxxx).then().extract().response();

Comment: Yes its done now. Thanks @va

Comment: @WilfredClement a GET request can certainly have a payload! It is not common, but it is definitely possible in HTTP. Some frameworks do not allow it, but the protocol does.